# Proving that $(-1)^n$ fails to converge in $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-explanation

I know how to prove that the sequence $(-1)^n$ fails to converge in $\mathbb{R}$. The proof I have in mind is:

> Suppose for the sake of contradiction that $s_n \to L$ for some $L \in \mathbb{R}$. Then there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ so that for all $n \geq N$, $|s_n - L| < 1$. In particular, take $n = 2N$ and $m = 2N + 1$, both of which are greater than $N$. Then:
> \begin{align*}
> & |(-1)^n - L| = |(-1)^{2N} - L| < |1 - L| < 1 \\ 
> & |(-1)^m - L| = |(-1)^{2N + 1} - L| < |-1-L| < 1. 
> \end{align*}
> Expanding the absolute values:
> \begin{align*}
> & |1 - L| < 1 \iff -1 < 1 - L < 1 \iff -2 < -L < 0 \iff L \in (0,2) \\ 
> & |1-L| < 1 \iff -1 < -1 - L < 1 \iff 0 < -L < 2 \iff L \in (-2,0). 
> \end{align*}
> So $L \in (0,2) \cap (-2,0) = \emptyset$, which is a contradiction.

I'm trying to strengthen this argument to prove that the sequence $(-1)^n$ fails to converge in $\mathbb{C}$. So the first step, following the above model, should be to suppose that it converges to some $L \in \mathbb{C}$. The proof breaks down because absolute value in $\mathbb{C}$ has a completely different meaning than absolute value in $\mathbb{R}$, so the above algebra I just wrote out does not carry over.

I'd appreciate any hints on how to prove this.

Comment: I mean ... if it doesn't converge in the subset $\Bbb R$, it definitely doesn't converge in the set $\Bbb C$. After all, the complex modulus and the absolute value coincide on the reals.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer I'm not sure I understand why, because in the scenario I posited, $\mathbb{L}$ was a complex number, so my expansion of the absolute values wouldn't be valid.

Comment: The triangle inequality tells you than $|s_n - s_{n+1}|\le |s_n-L| + |s_{n+1}-L|$

Comment: @Gribouillis I think you've used the fact that if $s_n$ is convergent, it is Cauchy, which I'm ok with; but I'm not sure how this leads to a contradiction.

Comment: Simply compute $|s_n - s_{n+1}|$ in this case.

Comment: Oh, I understand. One is even and the other odd. So no matter what, it comes out to $|1 - (-1)| = |-1 - 1| = |-2| = 2$, and I can make that smaller than anything I want. Excellent; thank you.

Comment: "The proof breaks down because absolute value in C has a completely different meaning than absolute value in R".... No, it doesn't.  ...."absolute value in C has a completely different meaning than absolute value in R"  They are actually exactly the same:  $|z| =\sqrt{z\cdot \overline z}$.  If $z \in \mathbb R$ then $z =\overline z$ and $|z| =\sqrt{z^2}$.  Same definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The proof breaks down because absolute value in C has a completely different meaning than absolute value in R,"

No, it does not.  The absolute value in $\mathbb C$ is *exactly* the same as the absolute value in $\mathbb R$.

The definition in $\mathbb R$ is $|x| = \sqrt{x^2} = \begin{cases}x&x \ge 0\\ -x&x< 0\end{cases}$.

And the definition in $\mathbb R$ is $|z| = \sqrt{z\cdot \overline z}$.

Now if $x \in \mathbb R \subset \mathbb C$ then $x = x + 0i = x - 0i = \overline x$.  And $|x| = \sqrt{x\cdot \overline x} =\sqrt{x \cdot x} = \sqrt{x^2} =|x|$.

No difference in definition and no different in your proof.

.....

Oh, I see.  The issue is $|1-L| < 1 \implies -1 < 1-L < 1$.  We can't do that with complex as complex do not have order and are not either positive or negative or $0$.

But the idea is still the same.  We can't have $L$ be "near" both $1$ and $-1$ but because $1$ and $-1$ are far ($2$) apart and any small neighborhoods around $1$ and $around $-1$ will be disjoint.

Here in complex number $|1-L| < 1$ means the $L$ is within a circle of radius $1$ centered at the point $1 = 1 + 0i$.  Whereas $|-1-L| < $ implies $L$ is within a circle of radius $1$ centered at the point $- 1 = -1+0i$.  The circle have no intersection.

... or to make this less handwavy:

Notice this basic fact.  If $|z| = \sqrt{Re^2(z) + Im^2(z)}$.  As $Re(z), Im(z)$ *are* real numbers we know that $Re^2(z),Im^2(z)$ are both non-negative real numbers and therefore $|z|=\sqrt{Re^2(z) + Im^2(z)}\ge \sqrt{Re^2(z)} = |Re(z)|$. (Likewise $|z| \ge |Im(z)|$.)

So although we can't so $|z| < d \implies -d < z < d$ we can say $|z|< d\implies |Re(z)|\le |z| < d \implies -d < |Re(z)| < -d$.

So what is $Re(1-L)$ and what is $R(-1-L)$.  Well $\pm 1 =\pm 1 + 0i$ and $L = Re(L) + iIm(L)$ so $\pm 1 - L = (\pm 1- Re(L)) + i(0 -Im(L))$ and $Re(\pm 1 - L) = \pm -Re(L)$.

Now your proof will work just fine!

$|-1-L| < 1\implies |Re(-1-L)|\le |-1-L|< 1\implies |-1-Re(L)|< 1 \implies $-1 < -1 -Re(L) < 1\implies -2 < Re(L) < 0$ whereas $|1-L| < 1\implies... $|Re(1-L)|=|1-Re(L)|< 1\implies -1  < 1-Re(L)< 1\implies 0< Re(L) < 2$ which are contradictory.

Comment: Please pardon my ignorance on this, but does anything at all change if $L$ has a non-zero imaginary component? In that case, $(-1)^n - L$ also has a non-zero imaginary component. That's my big worry.

Comment: If $L = a+bi$ then $(-1)^n -L = ((-1)^n -a) + bi$.  You can do your proof by considering that $|-1 - L| =|L - (-1)| = |L + 1| =|(1+a) +bi| \le |1+a|$ whereas $|1-L|=|L-1| = |(a-1)+ bi|\le |1-a|$.   So you have $-1 < a-1< 1$ and $-1< a+1 < 1$ and .... all works as planned.

Comment: I hadn't even considered making such an estimate. This is immensely helpful. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

In any case, $(s_{2n})$ clearly has limit 1 and  $(s_{2n+1})$ clearly has limit -1, since these two sequences are constant. This means the sequence $(s_n)$ has no limit. Being in $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ changes nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Just reduce it to what you have already proved.

If a sequence of real numbers $x_{n}$ has a limit, then the limit is a real number. This is because if the limit were some $a+bi$ with $b>0$ ($b<0$), then the imaginary part of $x_{n}$ would have to be positive (negative) for $n$ large enough, but each $x_{n}$ is real. Therefore, if the sequence has no limit in the real numbers, it has no limit in the complex numbers. No trickery with absolute values is required.